# Usage of the colon in this sentence (and alternatives)

Tags: colons

Is the colon used in the following sentence correct? If so, would it be better to replace it with a semicolon or a period?

> As CPUs get faster and faster, it is important that the performance of the memory system keeps pace: otherwise, the speed of the overall system will be compromised by the memory system bottleneck.

Comment: 'Correct' but dated. A semicolon is the formal choice; two sentences or a dash would be less formal options.

Comment: Are the two colons in the following sentence also "'Correct' but dated"? 
>So, with a direct mapped cache there is no need for a lengthy search of the cache: we simply calculate the index from the block address and check only one slot in the cache: if the block we want isn’t there, it isn’t in the cache at all.

Comment: It's never been considered acceptable to use two colons (in non-special usages like times, ratios, Bible references) in the same sentence. Here, I'd use a full stop, and a semicolon.